# Update different columns in different tables based on column value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to what is wrote in the question, probably is a stupid question but I can't find a solution, basically this is what I would like to do:

```
if(a.operator_id!=0){
    UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a ,".$SupportUserTable." b 
    SET a.title=? , a.priority=?, a.ticket_status=?, 
    b.solved_tickets= CASE 
        WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.solved_tickets+1) 
        ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
    b.assigned_tickets= CASE  
        WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) 
        ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,a.ticket_status='0' 
    WHERE a.enc_id=? AND b.id=a.operator_id
}
else{
    UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a ,".$SupportUserTable." b 
    SET a.title=? , a.priority=?, a.ticket_status=?
        ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,a.ticket_status='0' 
    WHERE a.enc_id=?
}
```

When `a.operator_id=0` there isn't a value for `b.id` that will match the condition
Is there a way to do this in only one query? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think that your branch ELSE is wrong:

   ```
   ...
   else{
   UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a ,".$SupportUserTable." b 
   SET a.title=? , a.priority=?, a.ticket_status=?
       ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,a.ticket_status='0' 
   WHERE a.enc_id=?
   }
   ```
2. You can create one or two srored procedures with a dynamicSQL inside and put tablenames as a parameter into there. for example:

   ```
   DELIMITER $$
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_proc $$
   CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc (IN SupportTicketsTable VARCHAR(20), IN SupportUserTable VARCHAR(20))
   BEGIN
   SET @SQLS = CONCAT('UPDATE ',SupportTicketsTable, 'a ', SupportUserTable,' b 
       SET a.title=? , a.priority=?, a.ticket_status=?, 
       b.solved_tickets= CASE 
          WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.solved_tickets+1) 
          ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
       b.assigned_tickets= CASE  
          WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) 
          ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,
       a.ticket_status='0' 
       WHERE a.enc_id=? AND b.id=a.operator_id';

   PREPARE STMT FROM @SQLS;
   EXECUTE STMT;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

   END$$
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I have solved it simply by changing from AND into OR